# With the expansion of the universe is time also increasing?

Tags: space-time, expansion, observable-universe

With more space being created would there be more time in that new region formed? Is the over all universe increasing in time? This is my first question so go easy on me. PS. Would that also mean that the kinetic energy of the universe is increasing? If not what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by time "increasing"? Trivially, time is always steadily progressing, but what does that have to do with the expansion of space?

Comment: With time and space being linked with new space being created. Would that mean there is more time to?

Comment: What I should have asked is How does the expansion of the universe affect time? How does time affect the newly expanded region of space?